# Mongodb: Can insert only not exists data?

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, exists

I have a sample data, like:

```
data = {'tag':'ball','color':'red'}
```

I want insert it to my collection. But if it has a same one, then do not insert.
I can do it in python like:

```
if not collection.find_one({data}):
    collection.insert(data)
```

Or, I can do it with update:

```
collection.update(data,data,upsert=True)
```

But, my question is: weather the 'update' write data every time?

In this two method, they search same times for the duplicate data, but in 1st way, only write while not exist.

In 2nd way, is it means if data not exists, insert one. if data exists, update one. The database would be wrote in all situation?

So, which method is better? and why?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a situation where I only want to write to the database if a record doesn't exist. In this case your first method is better.

For the 2nd way, the database would be written in all situation. However, if you want certain field not to be updated, you can try $setOnInsert as explained here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/